# Editing new products in my seeds.rb file creates a copy instead of editing the file I changed

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I'm new to Ruby and Rails so I really appreciate any feedback.
In my web application, I have six products I added to my products page through my `seeds.rb` file but I encountered a problem every time I try to edit any one of them.

Once I'm done with the edit, I run `rake db:seed` and reload my webpage (local host) but instead of showing the edit on the item I changed, a new version of the updated item shows up instead of simply running the edit. For example, if I change the color of one of the bikes and save the changes in the `seeds.rb` file, run `rake db:seed` and reload my page, a copy of the item I edited shows up instead of simply changing the color field on the existing item.

Code in `seeds.rb`:

[image: code in seeds.rb]

Web app:

[image: web app]

I was just wondering if there is something I'm missing.  My solution has been to delete the product through the "destroy" button on the page and simply run `rake db:seed` again.  If I'm doing something wrong, I'd greatly appreciate if you guys could point me in the right direction.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `rake db:reset` after you edit seeds.rb. Although it's worth noting that rake:seeds is usually reserved for initial creation of your app. You should generally be editing through your app (using localhost:3000/products/:id/edit ).